# jquery: get descendants of a parent with hiearchy intact

Tags: jquery

consider the following example

```
div > h1 > p > a
```

`div.children()` gives the immediate children which is `h1`

of course i use `find('*')` to get all descendants.

however, i need `div.find( h1 > p > a)` **not** `div.find(h1,p,a)`, which is what the default find('*') is doing: it is simply ignoring the original hiearchy.

*please note that div can be anything. the whole hiearchy can vary in depth.*
ie) div > h1 > span > b > i > a  and etc....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but have you tried [ancestor descendant](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant) instead of [parent > child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild) (you mention that your hierarchy can be of any depth, parent > child will only look for *immediate* children):

```
div.find('h1 p a')
```

Comment: the thing is , i need the h1 p a structure itself given the parent. i cannot control which parent is being selected.

Comment: @gpo - did you try the above?

Comment: yes. it works but like i mentioned, the hiearchy varies and i cannot control. what i need is to find() the descendant hiearchy of the given parent.